# Manga about siblings moving to the countryside and a selfish God

Tags: story-identification, manga

I don't really remember much but I read this manga a year maybe two years ago.

It involves two siblings who are moving to the countryside (or mountains) to live with distant relatives (an older couple). There is this selfish (kinda hot headed) God (the word Tori comes to mind) he wants the elder brother to inherit the family name.

There is a scene where the girl (sister) gets lost in the forest (mound of tears... Saddness...?) And she befriend another girl that can turn into a dog...?

Answer (score 1):

I found the manga it's called Matsuru Kami... I think it's been dropped though

Comment: Can you add more references and explain how/why this fits the OP's requirements?